# What is a node in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the Firebase Realtime Database security docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart, they mention nodes. However, I can't seem to figure out what a node is in Firebase. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read the documentation about [structuring your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data).  If you don't already understand that, then security rules are going to be difficult to reason about.  From that page:

> All Firebase Realtime Database data is stored as JSON objects. You can
>   think of the database as a cloud-hosted JSON tree. Unlike a SQL
>   database, there are no tables or records. When you add data to the
>   JSON tree, it becomes a node in the existing JSON structure with an
>   associated key.

And:

> When you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve
>   all of its child nodes. In addition, when you grant someone read or
>   write access at a node in your database, you also grant them access to
>   all data under that node. Therefore, in practice, it's best to keep
>   your data structure as flat as possible.

A node is just a location in the database, like other tree-like data structures in computer science.